# MongoDB: count both matching documents and matching subdocuments, grouped by property of document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given a collection of documents each containing an array of subdocuments (among other properties):

```json
    {
        "prop1": False,
        "prop2": "unique_value",
        "subdocuments": [
            {
                "subprop1": 1,
                "subprop2": 10
            },
            {
                "subprop1": 30,
                "subprop2": 40
            },
            {
                "subprop1": 10,
                "subprop2": 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

And a $match query covering both documents and subdocuments:

```js
    {
        "prop1": False,
        "$or": [
            {"subdocuments.subprop1": {"$lt": 3}},
            {"subdocuments.subprop2": {"$lt": 5}}
        ]
    }
```

How can I create an aggregate query that returns the number of **matching subdocuments and matching documents, grouped by a specific property of the root documents**?

Just counting total subdocuments and matching documents is simple, but I'm struggling to also get the right count of matching subdocuments.

Ideally I'd like to have a result like this (if we consider the sample document, only subdoc 1 and 3 match the $or conditions):

```json
    {
        "unique_value": {
            "documents": 1,
            "subdocuments": 2
        }
    }
```

In this case the results are being grouped by the value of "prop2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$size` and `$filter` to get the count for matching subdocuments first. Then do a `$sum` to get the documentCount and subdocumentCount.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "prop1": false,
      "$or": [
        {
          "subdocuments.subprop1": {
            "$lt": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "subdocuments.subprop2": {
            "$lt": 5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "subdocumentCount": {
        $size: {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$subdocuments",
            "as": "s",
            "cond": {
              "$or": [
                {
                  $lt: [
                    "$$s.subprop1",
                    3
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $lt: [
                    "$$s.subprop2",
                    5
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$prop2",
      documentCount: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      subdocumentCount: {
        $sum: "$subdocumentCount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      k: "$_id",
      v: {
        documentCount: "$documentCount",
        subdocumentCount: "$subdocumentCount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      docs: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "docs": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$docs"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$docs"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WWW4tLmOz-M) for your reference.

Comment: This solution works but it contains redundant matching/filtering. You can omit the "$match" block when you're just interested in the document counts.

Comment: @nulldroid I guess it would be more performant to put the filtering stage at earlier stage, as it helps reduce the size of intermediate result.

Comment: I think you misunderstood part of my question. In the end you group by a string called unique value. I want to group by a property, which in my case was prop2, and in my example document had "unique_value" as its value. Consider [this playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EiTFYz0K_jS) where prop2 has a different value in each document. They're still grouped by "unique_value" with your code.

Comment: @IhateJS That's a valid comment. I have updated the answer by replacing the $group key with the unique value (i.e. prop2) in your example. The remaining stages are just cosmetics to get your expected form.